# A non-$p$-adic proof of a congruence of Bernoulli numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, bernoulli-numbers

In *[A Multimodular Algorithm for Computing Bernoulli Numbers](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-2010-02367-1)*, Harvey uses the following congruence for Bernoulli numbers:

$$B_k \equiv \frac{k}{1-c^k} \sum_{x=1}^{p-1} x^{k-1} h_c(x)\quad(\text{mod}\ p)$$
where $p \ge 5$ is prime; $k$ is an even integer satisfying $2 \le k \le p - 3$; $c$ is an integer satisfying $0 < c < p$ and $c^k \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$, and
$$h_c(x) := \frac{(x\,\text{mod}\,p) - c(x / c\,\text{mod}\,p)}{p} + \frac{c-1}{2}$$
He says that this follows by reading Theorem 2.3 in Chapter 2 of Lang's *[Cyclotomic Fields 1](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-0987-4)* modulo $p$. The theorem in question is stated by Lang like this:
$$\frac{1}{k} B_k = \frac{1}{1-c^k} \int_{\mathbf{Z}_p} x^{k-1}\ \text{d}E_{1,c}(x)$$
Now unfortunately I don't know anything about $p$-adic analysis, so this is a bit beyond me.

I was wondering if there is a more direct proof of the congruence Harvey uses that does not rely on $p$-adic analysis.

Comment: Indeed I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{floor}[1]{\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor}$

*I doubt that this answer is still useful to you, since this question is one year old. Anyway, I'll leave the answer here, and maybe it will help someone (or not).*

Your congruence is, modulo details, a special case of a congruence due to Voronoi.  Let $k$ be an even positive integer, and write $B_k=\dfrac{N_k}{D_k}$ in lowest terms with $D_k>0$. Let $a$ and $n$ be coprime positive integers. Voronoi congruence states [2, Proposition 9.5.20]
that
\begin{equation}
\tag{1}\label{voronoin}
(a^k-1)N_k\equiv D_kka^{k-1}\sum_{x=1}^{n-1} x^{k-1}\floor{\frac{ax}{n}} \quad(\mathrm{mod}\ n),
\end{equation}
where $\floor{x}$ is the usual floor function.
Note that both sides are integers.

Let $n=p$ a prime number, and suppose $D_k$ is not divisible by $p$. Thus $p\ge5$ since $D_k$ is always divisible by $6$, by Clausen-von Staudt which states that [2, Corollary 9.5.15]
$$D_k=\prod_{(\ell-1)\mid k}\ell,$$
the product being over all primes $\ell$ such that $\ell-1$ divides $k$. Then \eqref{voronoin}
can be written as
\begin{equation}
\tag{2}\label{voronoip}
(a^k-1)B_k\equiv ka^{k-1}\sum_{x=1}^{p-1} x^{k-1}\floor{\frac{ax}{p}} \quad(\mathrm{mod}\ p).
\end{equation}

Let $c$ be a positive integer (coprime to $p$)
such that $ac\equiv 1 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ p)$, and for simplicity write $a=c^{-1}$, being an inverse modulo $p$. (Obviously $c$ can be chosen such that $0<c<p$ as in your statement.)
Multiplying both sides in \eqref{voronoip} by $c^k$ we obtain
\begin{equation}
\tag{3}\label{voronoic}
(1-c^k)B_k\equiv k\sum_{x=1}^{p-1} x^{k-1}c\floor{\frac{c^{-1}x}{p}} \quad(\mathrm{mod}\ p).
\end{equation}
Now, $cc^{-1}=1+pN$ for some integer $N$, and we use this as follows to relate the summands with $h_c(x)$.
For $1\le x\le p-1$, so that $x=\left(x \, \mathrm{mod}\, p\right)$, we have
\begin{align*}
c\floor{\frac{c^{-1}x}{p}}
&=\frac{cc^{-1}x}{p}-\frac{c\left(c^{-1}x \; \mathrm{mod}\, p\right)}{p}
=\frac{x}{p}+Nx-\frac{c\left(c^{-1}x \; \mathrm{mod}\, p\right)}{p}\\
&=h_c(x)+Nx-\frac{c-1}{2},
\end{align*}
so that \eqref{voronoic} becomes
\begin{equation}
\tag{4}\label{voronoitemp}
(1-c^k)B_k\equiv k\sum_{x=1}^{p-1} x^{k-1}h_c(x)+
kN\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}x^{k}
-k\frac{c-1}{2}\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}x^{k-1}
\quad(\mathrm{mod}\ p).
\end{equation}
To get rid of the last two sums, recall that for all $q$ not divisible by $p-1$ one has [1, Lemma 2.5.1]
\begin{equation}
\notag%\tag{4}\label{modp3}
\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}x^{q}\equiv 0
\quad(\mathrm{mod}\ p).
\end{equation}
Now we use your hypothesis $2\le k\le p-3$; then both $k-1$ and $k$ are not divisible by $p-1$, and the above implies that the last two sums in \eqref{voronoitemp} are zero. Also under this hypothesis, Clausen-von Staudt implies that $p$ does not divide $D_k$, which was used in \eqref{voronoip}.
If moreover $c^k \not\equiv 1 \pmod p$ we finally arrive to your congruence
\begin{equation}
\notag%\tag{4}\label{modp3}
B_k\equiv 
\frac{k}{1-c^k}\sum_{x=1}^{p-1} x^{k-1}h_c(x)\quad(\mathrm{mod}\ p).
\end{equation}

[1] Cohen, Henri Number theory. Vol. I. Tools and Diophantine equations. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 239. Springer, New York, 2007.

[2] Cohen, Henri Number theory. Vol. II. Analytic and modern tools. Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 240. Springer, New York, 2007.

(The original article by Voronoi can be accesed [here](https://www.mathnet.ru/rus/khmo272). His congruence appears as Corollary IV in page 146.)

Comment: That *is* helpful. The pointer to Cohen's book was tremendously helpful. Thanks! This wasn't for anything super important, just a small side project of mine. So it doesn't really matter that I had to wait a bit for an answer.